# Could a window mounted wet cloth sheet chill a room?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, evaporation, cooling

Assuming there is a light wind, that construction is partly shaded and a constant water pouring and evaporation of the material is occurring due to the breeze.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Search term: “swamp cooler.”

Comment: You are asking about [evaporative cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler) on a grand scale with the continuous flow of air past the wet cloth a very important requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the humidity of the incoming air is low.  This is the "evaporative cooling" (swamp cooler) method used for air conditioning in very dry climates (e.g., Albuquerque, NM).  It is not effective if the incoming air is not dry (as in Houston).  See discussions on adiabatic saturation in a thermodynamics textbook, such as one by Sonntag and van Wylen.

Comment: That's true and maybe for further reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler

Answer (score 0):

To effectively cool a medium-sized room via evaporation requires about 12 square feet of evaporator surface and 4 inches of thickness of water-saturated evaporation pads plus about 1/3 horsepower worth of continuous air flow that does not recirculate, and several gallons/hour of water supply. The maximum temperature depression achievable in practice this way is about 20 degrees F assuming very low ambient humidity like in the desert.

In comparison, a window-mounted single wet sheet without a fan will be ineffective.